# What a right way to build comet application, using Java Servlets 2 on IBM Websphere AppServer

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, comet

I prefer long polling, but my implementation has some problems. I send ajax request to servlet, that run infinity loop:

```
do {
  // some process
} while (/* some process is not finished */);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the *Web messaging service*.
There is a lot to configure so it doesn't make sense to write all in an answer. [Here is a tutorial](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Leveraging_Reverse_AJAX_in_IBM_WebSphere_Portal_7.0_using_Dojo_CometD_and_Web_messaging_service)